# In how many ways you can climb up 8 steps if minimum and maximum numbers of steps you can take at a time are 1 and 6 respectively?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I tried forming cases. If the stairs are numbered from 0,8. I enlisted following cases.

0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
0,1,7,8
0,1,2,8
and so on....

But immediately I realized that the number of steps can be 2,3,4,5 even, and there would be so many cases to go from step 1 in this way. And when all that exhausts, I have to begin with step 2 and so on. Is there any efficient way to tackle this problem?

Comment: Stars and bars would get you the total number of ways.  Then exclude cases where you take $7$ or $8$ at once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going to step on step 0 and on step 8. Other than that, you can freely choose which other steps you want to step on. There are $2^7=128$ ways to choose the remaining steps to step on.

However, stepping on only 0 and 8 requires a stride that is 8 long, and that's illegal. And stepping on 0,1 and 8 or 0,7 and 8 both require strides that are 7 long, and that's illegal. Any other of the remaining 125 choices of steps to step on can be done with only strides that are at most 6 long.

Comment: Thank you, @Arthur. You're amazing with that approach, and at explaining things. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is an efficient way.

Let $N(n)$ be a number of ways from step $n$ to the last step.

Imagine you stay on step 7. There is only 1 way to get to step 8 from here. So $N(7) = 1$

Imagine you stay on step 6. You can get to step 7 (and there will be 1 way from there) and you can go to step 8 directly (1 way). $N(6) = N(7) + 1$.
If we define $N(8) = 1$ the formula will look prettier: $N(6) = N(7) + N(8)$

From step 5 you can get to steps 6, 7 and 8; so $N(5) = N(6) + N(7) + N(8) = 4$

And so forth, $N(0) = N(1) + N(2) + ... + N(6) = 125$

This approach still requires some manual calculations, but all of them are doable.